# Laravel fails to process jobs in a queue

Tags: php, bash, laravel, docker, laravel-queue

For starters, this is the list of processes inside my Docker container:

```
/var/www/html # ps aux
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 {php-fpm.sh} /bin/sh /php-fpm.sh
    6 root       0:02 /usr/sbin/crond
    8 root       0:00 /sbin/syslogd -D -s 500
   10 root       1:31 php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work --queue=mailer --sleep=3 --tries=3
   11 root       0:00 /usr/bin/logger -t mailer
   12 root       0:24 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
   25 root       0:02 /usr/sbin/crond
   30 root       0:01 /sbin/syslogd -D -s 500
13505 www-data   6:20 php-fpm: pool www
21682 www-data   0:17 php-fpm: pool www
21837 root       0:00 /bin/sh
22078 www-data   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
22123 root       0:00 ps aux
31186 root       0:00 /bin/sh
31301 root       0:00 /bin/sh
```

This is the entry point of my container:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Start cron daemon
/usr/sbin/crond

# Logger, max log file size 500Kb
/sbin/syslogd -D -s 500

( php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work \
    --queue=mailer \
    --sleep=3 --tries=3 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t mailer & )

# Run PHP-FPM
php-fpm -F
```

The problem is *php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work* does not process jobs in the qeueu.

For that to happen I have to log in to the container by running docker exec -it  /bin/sh and then run *php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work --queue=mailer --sleep=3 --tries=3* and it works just fine.

So the question is what's wrong.

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: docker run -d --name=$PHP_CONT_NAME \
        -v /tmp:/tmp \
        -v /data/ewf/web/uploads:/var/www/html/public/uploads \
        -v /data/ewf/web/images:/var/www/html/public/images \
        --link=$REDIS_CONT_NAME --link=$MONGODB_CONT_NAME \
        -e 'REDIS_HOST=$REDIS_CONT_NAME' -e 'MONGODB_HOST=$MONGODB_CONT_NAME' $image 

Maybe the problem is the process does not 'see' the env REDIS_HOST ?

Comment: Try changing `docker run -d` to `docker run -itd` and see if it helps

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: Try changing command to `php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work \ --queue=mailer \ --sleep=3 --tries=3 2>&1 > /tmp/worker.log` and Check if you get anything in logs